# Openshift, can't restart application "Another operation is already running"

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I'm trying to restart my application, but I receive an error :

Unable to perform action on app object. Another operation is already running

I've tried restarting it through the web portal, and rhc app-restart. Both show that error.

It looks like this issue was fixed in redhat, but I don't know how to apply it to my server. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1140378

I tried logging into my server and applying the fix by following this guide: https://access.redhat.com/articles/11258 , but I couldn't because I don't have root access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 'rhc app-force-stop ' . Then start your app.